# Problems with booting when using display port

Tags: windows, boot, drivers

I have had some problems with my pc lately, it seems to randomly fail to boot (the post screen runs, and the windows loading circle runs, but then the pc restarts and goes into recovery).

If i take out the GPU and use the motherboard instead, the pc boots but the screen is black, only flickering the desktop half a second every 10-20 second or so.

I have found i can fix it by plugging in the hdmi indstead of display port, and then change it back after boot. The fix persists through restart.

I have tried the following:

- new GPU+motherboard+CPU
- Reformat

Upon reformating i have seen the problem occour before i got to setup the environment, and after 1-2 days of usage.

My ntbootlog ends with theese lines (theese are from a few days ago, before i changed to new hardware, but symptoms are the same):

> BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem14.inf,%nvidia_dev.1b80.3367.1462%;NVIDIA
>   GeForce GTX 1080 BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem6.inf,%ibt_usb%;Intel(R)
>   Wireless Bluetooth(R) BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @oem28.inf,%nic_9560ac_2x2_hmc%;Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560
>   BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem2.inf,%e15bcnc.devicedesc%;Intel(R) Ethernet
>   Connection (7) I219-V BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   AFD.SYS BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED AFD.SYS BOOTLOG_LOADED
>   \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\WUDFRd.sys BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED AFD.SYS
>   BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @audioendpoint.inf,%msft.audioendpoint%;Audio
>   Endpoint BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @audioendpoint.inf,%msft.audioendpoint%;Audio Endpoint
>   BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @audioendpoint.inf,%msft.audioendpoint%;Audio
>   Endpoint BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft
>   Kernel Debug Network Adapter BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
>   @c_swdevice.inf,%swd\genericraw.devicedesc%;Generic software device
>   BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED AFD.SYS BOOTLOG_LOADED
>   \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\condrv.sys BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED AFD.SYS
>   BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED AFD.SYS BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED AFD.SYS
>   BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED AFD.SYS

My screen setup:
two dell u2415h daisy chained with dp 1.2
The slave screen has the jack from the speakers.

Further notes:
I had my PSU replaced due to failure 4 month ago, so it should also be brand new.

Specs:
 - ASUS ROG STRIX Z390-I GAMING
 - i7-9700k
 - Corsair Vengeance LPX - DDR4 - 16 GB : 2 x 8 GB
 - MSI RTX 2080 Ti ventus
 - Corsair RMx Series RM750x

edit: The part of the bootlog that actually loads

```
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\mup.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\iorate.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\hwpolicy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\disk.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @hal.inf,%acpi_amd64.devicedesc%;ACPI x64-based PC
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @kdnic.inf,%kdnic.devicedesc%;Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succesfully found it to be the display port on my main screen.

I stopped turning my pc off due to the problem, and usually my monitors would not be shut down but be in sleep over night. One day however, i had the main screen shut down during the night. Upon turning the screen on the next day, the pc restarted.

I have now changed the main monitor, and the pc no longer has boot/startup issues but the suspected faulty screen will go black for a few seconds from time to time.